# Error message: "Operation value must be a number", on creation of new JIRA issue

Tags: vba, jira-rest-api

When creating a new JIRA issue using REST API in VBA, I'm getting the following error message for custom field 13744: "Operation value must be a number".

I've tested the following code without the numeric field, and everything works fine, the issue is created and all the other fields value are passed:

```
Public Pass As Variant
```

```
 Sub criarIssue()

    Dim JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim sErg As Variant
    Dim sRestAntwort As Variant
    Dim sSummary As Variant
    Dim sDescription As Variant
    Dim sProject As Variant
    Dim sIssueType As Variant
    Dim sData As Variant
    Dim sPath As Variant
    Dim sUsername As Variant
    Dim sPassword As Variant
    Dim sAux As Variant
    Dim sStatus As Variant
    Dim sEncbase64Auth As Variant

    sUsername = Environ$("UserName")
    Senha.Show

    sPassword = Pass

    sSummary = ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value 'Issue name
    sIssueType = "Projeto"
    sProject = "EXP"

    sData = " { ""fields"" : { ""project"" : { ""key"" : """ & sProject & """ }, ""summary"" : """ & _
    sSummary & """, ""issuetype"" : { ""name"" : """ & sIssueType & """}, ""customfield_13744"" : ""1234"", ""customfield_13663"" : {""name"" : ""vitor.ribeiro""}, ""customfield_13670"" : ""2019-01-23 00:00:00"", ""customfield_13671"" :  {""value"" : ""SP"" , ""child"" : {""value"" : ""SAO PAULO"" }}}} "

    sEncbase64Auth = EncodeBase64(sUsername & ":" & sPassword)

    'Creates Issue
    With JiraService
        .Open "POST", "http://172.16.2.128:8080/rest/api/2/issue/", False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck"
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & sEncbase64Auth
        .Send (sData)
        sRestAntwort = .ResponseText
        sStatus = .Status & " | " & .StatusText
    End With

    ' JSON Response
    sAux = Replace(sRestAntwort, "{", "")
    sAux = Replace(sAux, "}", "")
    sAux = Split(sAux, ",")
    sAux = sAux(1)
    sAux = Split(sAux, ":")
    sAux = sAux(1)
    sAux = Replace(sAux, """", "")

    ActiveSheet.Range("J2").Value = sStatus
    ActiveSheet.Range("J3").Value = sRestAntwort & " | " & sAux
    ActiveSheet.Range("J4").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("J4").Value + 1
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = sAux

    With JiraService
    .Open "DELETE", "http://172.16.2.128:8080/rest/auth/1/session", False
        .Send
        End With


End Sub
```

```
Public Function EncodeBase64(text As String) As String

    Dim arrData() As Byte
    arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)

    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.text

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

End Function
```

All but custom field 13744 values are passed without a problem.

For this one I get the following error message:

{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_13744":"Operation value must be a number"}

Why isn't it recognized as a number?

Comment: pass your value as int `""customfield_13744"" : 1234,`  i.e. without quotes

Comment: And that was all! It works fine now! Thanks a lot @cyboashu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just had to pass de numeric value without quotes, as suggested by @cyboashu. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You must delete punctuation mark "